# dt (float left) and first dd (float right) on the same line

Tags: css, css-float

I am using a definition list to define sections of a resume.

I would like to have each dt and its first dd to show on the same line. The dt should be on the left, and the dd on the right. I would like the remaining dds for each dt to show below the dt.

I also need this to be responsive, so as the screen width decreases the first dd goes to the next line.

Right now, I can't seem to get the floats to clear at the right point.

Any ideas?

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/WgkZp/

**HTML:**

```
<dl> 
<dt class="position">Position Name 1</dt>
<dd class="side-time clearfix">
    <time datetime="2010-08-01" class="start">August 2010</time><span class="end">Present</span>
</dd>
<dd class="organization first">Organization Name</dd>
<dd>Location, USA</dd>
<dd class="additional">
    <ul>
        <li>Described task 1</li>
        <li>Described tesk 2</li>
    </ul>
</dd> <dt class="position">Position Name 2</dt>

<dd class="side-time clearfix">
    <time datetime="2010-08-01" class="start">August 2010</time><span class="end">Present</span>
</dd>
<dd class="organization first">Organization Name</dd>
<dd>Location, USA</dd>
<dd class="additional">
    <ul>
        <li>Described task 1</li>
        <li>Described tesk 2</li>
    </ul>
</dd> <dt class="position">Position Name 3</dt>

<dd class="side-time clearfix">
    <time datetime="2010-08-01" class="start">August 2010</time><span class="end">Present</span>
</dd>
<dd class="organization first">Organization Name</dd>
<dd>Location, USA</dd>
<dd class="additional">
    <ul>
        <li>Described task 1</li>
        <li>Described tesk 2</li>
    </ul>
</dd>
```

**CSS:**

```
dl {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

dt {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}

dt.first {
  margin: 0;
}

dd {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

dd ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

dd time, dd .end {
  font-style: italic;
}

dd time.start:after {
  content:'\2013';
}

dd.side-time {
  float: right;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove that margin from the top of the `dt`. It's pushing it down into the second line. Add `clear:both` to the location `dd` to keep it on a new line below the floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dd {
    clear:both;
}

dt + dd{
    clear: none;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WgkZp/1/

Comment: This seems to work except that I would like the time/date to align left when it's moved to a new line because the screen width decrease. Any way to do this without a media query?

Comment: Not that I can think of without javascript.